# R Wildcard matching for certain number of terms

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have a string and am searching for particular wildcard terms. For example:

```
x <- "AJSDKLAFJASFJABJKADL"
z <- stri_locate_all_regex(x, 'A*****AF')
```

I want to search for all terms that have any 5 characters in between A and AF, like ABJDKAAF or AJSDKLAF... However the above code does not work. Is there a simple way to do this that I am overlooking? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regular expressions (as opposed to standard wildcards that you might be used to), `*` means "0 or more of the preceding character", so "A*" means "0 or more A". You can't stack them like '****', for that you want '.' which means "one character".

```
z <- stri_locate_all_regex(x, 'A.....AF')
```

TL,DR: regex problem, not R problem.

Comment: and concisely, `'A.{5}AF'`

Answer (score 2):

For a **simple way** to do this, and by this I assume you mean that you want to use your wildcard characters as in the question, you can turn these into proper regular expressions using `glob2rx()`.  A "wildcard" expression, also known as a "[glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))", is a sort of poor man's regular expression (`?regex`).  For your expression, you can specify five `?` characters, because in a glob, `?` means any single character.

```
x <- c("ABCDEFAF", "XABCDEFAFX", "abcdeaf", "A55555AF", "A666666AF")

# the (simpler?) "wildcard" way
stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, glob2rx("A?????AF"))
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# the regular expression way (probably WRONG)
stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, "A.{5}AF")
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# the regular expression way (CORRECT)
stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, "^A.{5}AF$")
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This returns a logical vector if the wildcard matches.

By contrast, `stri_locate_all_regex()` returns a list of matrixes of dimensions 1, 2 where the columns are the starting and ending character positions of the matches within the string, or a pair of `NA` values if the pattern is not found.

Note that one of the differences in your wildcard/glob expression is that to get `A` + any five characters + `AF` without any preceding or trailing characters, you would need to specify the regular expression characters for the start and end of the string, as per above.  Otherwise the match picks up `"XABCDEFAFX"` too.  For a wildcard/glob, this is not a problem since the start and end of the expression match the beginning and end of the string:

```
> glob2rx("A?????AF")
[1] "^A.....AF$"
```